# iOS:Multipart data -form error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In this I try to do Multi form data.But i received a internal error because my data is not proper.

I want to set `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data" my parameter to data I don't know how to do.Here is my code

```
NSString *stringUrl =@"http://URL";
//    NSString *mimetype = @"image/jpeg";

UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"1418954654.png"];
NSData *imageDataa = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
NSDictionary *parameters  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name",@"first_name",@"name2",@"last_name",@"10-03-2356",@"dob",@"test@gmail.com",@"email",@"12452",@"facebook_id",@"M",@"gender",@"123456",@"password",@"12345689",@"phone_no",@"U",@"user_type", nil];
//

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl]];
// NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@ ;", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n,", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];


if (imageDataa) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.jpg\r\n", @"photo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageDataa];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   // NSLog(@"bodu%@",body);
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@d--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// NSLog(@"bodu%@",body);

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
 NSLog(@"bodyy%@",postLength);

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
        //success
        NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"==%@",newStr);
    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"==%@",error.localizedDescription);

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Upload the image to server using AfNetworking multipart and the code is given below,

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(NSString *)member withUserImageData:(NSData*)imageData completion:(WebServiceStatusCompletionBlock)completionBlock {

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 memberVal: member,
                                 };

    [self.httpRequestOperationManager POST:URL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if(imageData)
        {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"Photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (responseObject) {
            completionBlock(nil, responseObject);
        } else {
            completionBlock(responseObject, nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

//          completionBlock(error, nil);

        completionBlock(error, operation.responseObject);
    }];
}
```

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issues I missed out the key "data".

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"data"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```